# laravel-filemanager showing error after transfer application from local host to live hosting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, tinymce, file-manager

I have installed TinyMCE and Laravel-file manager. Here are the referring links which I followed-

- https://www.tinymce.com
- https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager

Now everything works well on my localhost. Attaching an image of successful output to localhost
[success in localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNtoB.png)

Now After uploaded my application into the live server while I was trying to upload the image, I have faced file manager showing me an error and it doesn't work. 
This is the error image I got-
[Error image while uploading application on live server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyqNv.png)

Anyone, please help me find the solution and tell me what should I do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 2 errors in my files and 1 in my cpanel and i made those errors while uploading my project from localhost to live server(tzipor.com/tz). I had to made correction two path while uploading to live server(tzipor.com/tz) but i did not do that. Those occurred the problem. Here i am explaining those-

1. I am using tinymce and i am integrating filemanager with that. I had to make correction to my tinymce editor file. Giving you a link of image referring to my localhost file. https://ibb.co/bZdwew
   the tinyeditor file, while in localhost, `path_absolute : "/"`, is the correct code. But this should be change based on my live server url. As my live server url the code should be `path_absolute : "/tz/",` https://ibb.co/c3TF6b
   So we need to careful here while upload project localhost to live server
2. in config/lfm.php this code was correct while my project was in my localhost- `'base_directory' => 'public',` .https://ibb.co/jKYezw But after upload project into live server this path should need to change based on my server link. As my live server link, this should be `'base_directory' => '../tz',` https://ibb.co/mVowew

3.In cpnael->select php version: make sure fileinfo have checked. https://ibb.co/gS9GUw

So we need to be careful in this three sections while upload project localhost to live server.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that your routes were cached with new entries:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

Also make sure you really installed the package running:

```
composer install
```

on live server.

Comment: I have tried with route:cache and i have installed composer also. this is the output i got [tzipodzo@server105 tz]$ php artisan route:cache
Route cache cleared!

In Route.php line 880:

  Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure.
But still no result. Please give me a solution. Can i talk with you in skype so i can show you by share my screen.